# .Net instance function pointer

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, delegates

Can I make a pointer to an instance function when I don't have the instance declared yet? Right now I'm using reflection to call my methods but it seems this could be easier with a delegate of sorts. I just can't figure it out. The methods I will call will always return the same type and have no parameters.

Here is some sample code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
Private Shared Function A() As Object

    Return Lauch(????) ' should call FunctionA of the instance (undeclared here)

End Function


Private Shared Function B() As Object

    Return Lauch(????) ' should call FunctionB of the instance (undeclared here)

End Function


Private Shared Function Lauch(Of T)(ByVal instanceFunc As Func(Of T)) As Object

    ' long and repetitive operations that I don't want to repeat in function A and B

    Dim myInstance As New MyClass()

    Return myInstance.instanceFunc()

End Function
```

Right now I'm doing something like the following and it works, but I feel there should be a better way:

```
Private Shared Function A() As Object

    Return Lauch("FunctionA")

End Function


Private Shared Function B() As Object

    Return Lauch("FunctionB")

End Function


Private Shared Function Lauch(ByVal instanceFunc As String) As Object

    ' long and repetitive operations that I don't want to repeat in function A and B

    Dim myInstance As New MyClass()

    Return myInstance.GetType().GetMethod(instanceFunc).Invoke(myInstance, Nothing))

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
Private Shared Function A() As Object
    Return Lauch(Function(x) x.A())
End Function


Private Shared Function Lauch(ByVal instanceFunc As Func(Of CustomClass, Object)) As Object
    ' long and repetitive operations
    Dim myInstance As New CustomClass()
    Return instanceFunc(myInstance)
End Function
```

Basically, you define the function that determines the result of the `Lauch` Function. This is a function that takes a `CustomClass` and returns an `Object`. In the `A` method you define this function to return the result of the instance's `A` function.

Comment: I would never have come up with this! Thanks, I'll have to debug it some more to really understand what's going on in there.